# Refresh select using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, html-select

I have `select` and `button`:

```
<select id="s">
  <option id="o1">O1</option>
  <option id="o2">O2</option>
</select>

<button id="a">O1 -> O11</button>
```

I want to see `O11` in select after pressing button:

```
$('#s').click(function(){
  $('#o1').text('O11');
})
```

But select refreshes only after clicking on select.

https://jsfiddle.net/dfwbLsn1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must bind the `click` event to the button:

```
$('#a').click(function(){
    $('#o1').text('O11');
});
```

That should do it.

**Edit:** Based on your comment, you also want to change the selected option with the button click. Note that you have *no mention of this* in your question.

To change the selected option, the options need values. This is how to achieve what you're after:

```
<select id="s">
    <option id="o1" value="1">O1</option>
    <option id="o2" value="2">O2</option>
</select>

<script>
$('#a').click(function() {
    $('#o1').text('O11');
    $('#s').val(1);
});
</script>
```

Now clicking the `<button>` also changes the value of the `<select>`.

Comment: what the difference between your code and code in question and in fiddle? You can try it on fiddle it is updated option but not refreshed select immediately - we need first click on button and then on select to see new value.

Comment: @user3479125 The difference is the `id` inside the selector. You have `$('#s')`, which binds the `click` event to the `<select>` element. I changed that to `$('#a')`, which is the `id` of your `<button>` element.

Comment: @user3479125 - did you read the first sentence of this answer, which actually does explain the difference?

Comment: @user3479125 I have updated the answer to also select the first `<option>` when clicking the `<button>`.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding click event with select click.

```
$('#s')  //this is you are binding with select
```

If you want to do something on button click, then you have to bind click event with button

```
$('#a').click(function(){
  $('#o1').text('O11');
})
```